# Выравнивание числа и вставка разделителей

Tags: python, format

Есть задача отобразить число, дополнив его лидирующими нулями до N знаков и добавив разделители между тысячами.

По отдельности это сделать несложно:

`f'{number:,}'` - вставить запятые между тысячами

`f'{number:09d}'` - дополнить до 0 знаков

А как и то, и то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да вроде всё работает, только запятые тоже считаются в числе знаков:

```py
number = 13323
print(f'{number:09,d}')
```

Вывод:

```
'0,013,323'
```

Comment: Вы правы, а я просто `d` и запятую местами перепутал. Спасибо

Comment: @АлексейСаровский Ну я тупо попробовал все возможные варианты расположения запятой и нашёл работающий )